# Android store static information in app

Tags: android, mapping, storage

I have a structure :

```
class Level {
   protected int id;
   protected String title;
   protected int levelValue;
}
```

This structure will be mapping from the source.(Sql,xml or raw).

**NOTE :** I know that i can store info in `SQLite` or `xml files` structure or `raw` file. And what the problem - this info is static. So this info is available only on **read**. No deletes, no updates, no inserts. All is static.

So i want a help from you. What is the best way to store static info?

Comment: for always static info like facebook app id I use public static final String fbId="mystaticstring". U dont need update delete insert so why not use it.

Comment: @IllegalArgument iknow about this. But if levels count more than - 1000? Or more?

Comment: use a database then storing so much informaiton in an object will certainly consume too much memory. You will likely face outofmemory error. And please update your question keeping in mind that the objects are more than 1000